# React set up error while running npm start :Configuration file found but no entry configured. Use --help to display the CLI options

Tags: reactjs

I am getting error while setting environment for my react app.
I have not done any thing as per coding prospective .
Its just a hello world programme in react.
I have also uploaded my node modules in the below given url .

I have put down my code in Github  : https://github.com/Arpan1089/reactapp

error :

> reactapp@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Sumeet\Desktop\reactapp
>   webpack-dev-server

Configuration file found but no entry configured.
Use --help to display the CLI options.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! reactapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 4294967295
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactapp@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs reactapp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls reactapp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sumeet\Desktop\reactapp\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: did yu use npm start command to run it on server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your `package.json` inside `scripts` tag

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
},
```

and install webpack-dev-server --hot and webpack-dev-server using

```
npm install webpack-dev-server
```

And may be you have another process running on the same port (8080) on localhost which will prevent your app to run.

Comment: A Vikram have you seen my package.json>

Comment: {
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
Its same  and i have also tried to with different ports .

Comment: have you installed webpack-dev-server and webpack?

Comment: can you please check if nod modules folder is present at location C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules

Comment: also share your webpack.config.js

Comment: yes i have done npm install webpack-dev-server
Package.json

{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
  }
  
}

Comment: share webpack.config.js not package.json